# Puppet epp conditionals is there elsif?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Q: does puppet [epp](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_epp.html) template syntax support `elsif` conditionals?

I am receiving the following error when building a template with puppet epp:

```
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, epp(): Invalid EPP: Syntax error at 'elsif'
```

It seems like puppet syntax should support the use of elsif [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_conditional.html#if-statements). I've looked around and can't seem to see much on this topic.

---

My template:

```
<% if $facts[env] == test  { %> foo:
    <% if $facts[site] == uk { %> bar uk: <% } %>
    <% elsif $facts[site] == fr { %> bar fr: <% } %>
    <% else $facts[site] == us { %> bar us: <% } %>
<% } %>
```

---

Latest Edits:

Along with John Bollinger's helpful comments below, there shouldn't be any conditions outside of the else. If there are, Puppet throws the misleading error message above. So for my use-case the below works well:

```
 <%
  if $facts[env] == test  {
    %> foo:
    <%
    if $facts[site] == uk    {
      %> bar uk: <%
    } elsif $facts[site] == fr {
      %> bar fr: <%
    } else {
      %> bar us: <%
    }
  }
 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is template text (albeit all whitespace) between the closing brace of the `if` block and the `elseif`.  From the perspective of the Puppet code, template text is effectively an output statement, and that cannot appear between an `}` and an `elsif`.

Since it seems unlikely that you actually want the particular whitespace that is causing the issue, I think you could resolve it by suppressing it:

```
<% if $facts[env] == test  { %> foo:
    <% if $facts[site] == uk { %> bar uk: <% } -%>
    <%- elsif $facts[site] == fr { %> bar fr: <% } -%>
    <%- else $facts[site] == us { %> bar us: <% } -%>
<% } %>
```

That leaves the linebreak and whitespace after `foo:`, but suppresses the whitespace between the `if` and `elseif`, between the `elseif` and `else`, and following the `else`.

Alternatively, I usually find template code easier to read when it has fewer tags.  Like this, maybe:

```
<%
  if $facts[env] == test  {
    %> foo:
    <%
    if $facts[site] == uk    {
      %> bar uk: <%
    } elsif $facts[site] == fr {
      %> bar fr: <%
    } else $facts[site] == us  {
      %> bar us: <%
    }
  }
 %>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, it's working! Though I've also just realized there's a rather obvious error in the 'else' in my original post. It should just be else {...} i.e. without any conditional logic